# How can I avoid adding blank rows by IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-sheets

When using IMPORTRANGE and range is going to be expand blank rows are added. How can I avoid that?

In the first picture you see that "ORIGINAL" contains original data and it is imported in "IMPORTED" by IMPORTRANGE function. "ROWS" contains a length of rows in "ORIGINAL". The entire code of the function is here; note that it refers row length to import exact range of data.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url", "ORIGINAL!A1:B" & ROWS!A1)
```

[image]

Then I added a row in "ORIGINAL". It is surely reflected on both "ROWS" and "IMPORTED" but blank rows are added and this is what I want to avoid. I hope this isn't a abandoned bug and solution exists.

[image]

Comment: Use `FILTER()` or `QUERY()` function to avoid those blank rows.

Comment: @Harun24hr Can I see a working example?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Harun24hr you must use it with `FILTER()` or `QUERY()` since the `ROWS()` function is literally just counting the number of rows of the specified range and not the actual range with data.

##### Try:

```
=ROWS(QUERY(Original!A:A,"Select A where A is not Null"))
```

or using `COUNTA()` which is a function that counts the values in the range

```
=COUNTA(Original!A:A)
```

##### Source Data:

[image]

##### Result:

[image]

##### References:

- [ROWS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382?hl=en)
- [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en)

---

#### UPDATE:

Upon clarifying in the comments in the comments here's an updated answer.

##### Explanation:

Unfortunately it is an expected behaviour of the `importrange()` since it is only pulling the data or the content of the cells and it will not import the formatting of the original sheet.

Here is more detailed explanation: [Using IMPORTRANGE to Reference Another Google Sheet](https://www.coursera.org/articles/tutorial-importrange-google-sheets)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but am afraid to say you misunderstand some points. Sheet "ORIGINAL" never contains blank row as shown in image. And my goal is not to count imported rows excluding blank ones but to import exact same range.

Comment: Hi @TakuyaHARA, apologies for misunderstanding your question. I understand you want to use the importrange() to pull the data from the original sheet with the same number of rows & columns which means it will only show 6 rows and 2 columns. This is an expected behaviour of the importrange function since it is only pulling the data or the content of the cells and it will not import the formatting of the original sheet.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why some extra rows are added, it there any official technical docs?

Comment: @TakuyaHARA here's a link explaining it https://www.coursera.org/articles/tutorial-importrange-google-sheets, see the limitations section. But it is not the official documentation from Google.